# Transparent border broken on android react native

Tags: android, css, react-native, border, transparent

Trying to make a transparent border around each cell on react native. It works perfectly on iOS but doesn't work on android, and instead produces a gray/shadow like border around cell. When I set border to 0 it works but I need border to be set to 2 for a different formatting issue.

I tried `border-color: transparent, #0000000`

```
const VerticalContainer = styled(Container)`
  justify-content: center;
  backgroundColor: white
  borderRadius: 8
  margin: 6px 0px
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px
  elevation: 1
  min-height: 70
  shadow-color: gray
  shadow-offset: 2px 2px
  shadow-opacity: 0.2
  shadow-radius: 4px
  border-width: 2
  border-color: transparent
`
```

[iOS transparent border that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANjVf.png)

[android with border not working as not transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prkir.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should check shadowColor, shadowOpacity and elevation on Android:

```
 someStyle: {
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        elevation: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : 0,
    },
```